# If use strictmode in my codes, will the security of login be weaken?

Tags: java, android, android-strictmode

Having some doubts on the importing the strict mode in my login application. If i enable this in my code,

```
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

will the security features in my login weakened? Or I should just use the async task?

Comment: Nope! It is just a **diagnostic tool** and it should be used during development not with the released app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since android version 3.0 there has been some restrictions of using the network related code in the main ui thread as it would cause ANR. Hence by putting the Strict mode thread policy in your code you are violating this restriction and you can use network related code in the main thread, This will not anyways weak your login feature.

Comment: What you mean by this line ?  Hence by putting the Strict mode thread policy in your code you are violating this restriction and you can use network related code in the main thread,

Comment: As i said before since andriod 3.0 no network calls from main ui thread, if you try doing that you will get an exception, if you really need to call the network on the ui thread you can do this by getting the permission from OS with the policy as in your code above

Comment: Yes. Cause i run using android 3.0 and there is network exception. thats why i tried using this strict mode. 

 So I use this code is just to turn it off so that my login application can work thats all?

Comment: There will not be any issue concerning your security, you don't have to worry about it

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.html), the default policy for `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy` is `LAX` "... which doesn't catch anything".  So unless something was previously setting a non-default policy, your code shouldn't change anything.